# How to store id and tags in some variable using tag-it

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I am using [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/).
This code is working properly. but problem is I am not able to get its id.
I want to get both id and tag (want to store in some hidden field ) value in my server side code.

By using `fieldName: "tagValues"` it is attaching a hidden field with tag name like `<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="school,college" name="tagValues">`

How can I store ids??.

Below is my code.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("#myTags").tagit({
                            singleField: true,
                            allowSpaces: false,
                            minLength: 2,
                            removeConfirmation: true,
                            tagLimit: 2,
                            fieldName: "tagValues",
                            placeholderText: "Tag your page (max 2)",
                            tagSource: function(request, response) {
                                console.log(request + " " + response);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "PageTagSuggestion",
                                    data: {term: request.term},
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        response($.map(data.tagList, function(item) {
                                            return {
                                                label: item.tag,
                                                value: item.tag,
                                                value1: item.id
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ));
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            onTagLimitExceeded: function(event, ui) {
                                alert("You are exceeding tag limit");
                            }, 
                        });
                    });
```

```html
 <ul id="myTags" name="tag"></ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to store an array of ids inside a hidden field? What would the resulting $_POST or $_GET be?

Comment: NO it is only showing only tag value not id. I am getting data using Post I want to get data in servlet

Comment: you want to know how to read from a tag-it field then?

Comment: Yes   want to store id and value